# Xpath expression for first sentence in a pagraph

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, domxpath

I'm looking for an Xpath expression for the first sentence in a paragraph.

```
<p>
A federal agency is recommending that White House adviser Kellyanne Conway be 
removed from federal service saying she violated the Hatch Act on numerous 
occasions. The office is unrelated to Robert Mueller and his investigation.
</p>
```

The result should be:

```
A federal agency is recommending that White House adviser Kellyanne Conway be 
removed from federal service saying she violated the Hatch Act on numerous 
occasions.
```

I've tried a few things to no avail.

```
$expression = '/html/body/div/div/div/div/p//text()';
```

Would I need to use: `//p[ends-with` or maybe `substring-before`?

Comment: You need to make it clear what XPath version you are using. This kind of thing is much easier in XPath 2.0 or later. You refer to `ends-with()`, which requires XPath 2.0, but you also mention PHP which would suggest you are limited to 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to parse natural language via XPath, but you can get the substring up to and including the first period as follows:

```
substring(/p,1,string-length(substring-before(/p,"."))+1)
```

Note that this may not be the "first sentence" if there are abbreviations or other lexical occurences of a period before the first sentence ends, if the first sentence ends with another form of punctuation, etc.

---

Alternatively, and more concisely:

```
concat(substring-before(/p, "."), ".")
```

**Credit:** [ThW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2265374/thw)'s clever idea in the comments.

Comment: I guess I could also explode() it and grab the first element in the array. Probably trying to do too much with XPath.

Comment: The above is about as good as you'll get in a single simple XPath; `explode()` won't be any better.  You'd need to employ a NLP library to operate at the semantic, sentence level rather than the lexical, punctuation level to really do it right.

Comment: I think that `substring-before(/p,'.')` is enough. The rest of the expression to get also the period might obfuscate `substring-before()` semantic.

Comment: @Alejandro: Indeed, I initially wrote only `substring-before(/p,'.')`, but then I saw that OP requested that "the result should be" output that includes the period, so I thought I'd take it a step further.  You're right, though, `substring-before()` is most important.

Comment: You could just append the dot again: `concat(substring-before(/p, "."), ".")`

Answer (score 1):

Here is no really good way to do it on the Xpath level. PHP has only Xpath 1.0 and support only basic string operations. Nothing that can take the locale/language into account. However PHP itself has something for it in `ext/intl`.

So fetch the text content of the paragraph element node using DOM+Xpath as an string and extract the first sentence from it.

`IntlBreakIterator` can split the a string according the locale/language specific rules.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<p>
A federal agency is recommending that White House adviser Kellyanne Conway be 
removed from federal service saying she violated the Hatch Act on numerous 
occasions. The office is unrelated to Robert Mueller and his investigation.
</p>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// fetch the first paragraph in the document as string
$summary = $xpath->evaluate('string((//p)[1])');
// create a break iterator for en_US sentences.
$breaker = IntlBreakIterator::createSentenceInstance('en_US');
// replace line breaks with spaces before feeding it to the breaker
$breaker->setText(str_replace(["\r\n", "\n"], '', $summary));

$firstSentence = '';
// iterate the sentences
foreach ($breaker->getPartsIterator() as $sentence) {
  $firstSentence = $sentence;
  // break after the first sentence
  break;
}

var_dump($firstSentence);
```

Output:

```
string(164) "A federal agency is recommending that White House adviser Kellyanne Conway be removed from federal service saying she violated the Hatch Act on numerous occasions. "
```

Additionally `DOMXpath` allows you to register PHP functions and call them from the Xpath expression. If you need that logic on the Xpath level (to use them in conditions) this is a possibility.

Comment: This is a useful addition leveraging the hosting language.